# Why Spacebars doesn't support like {{foo[0]}} but only support {{foo.[0]}}?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

`{{foo.[0]}}` is quite weird and if foo is array, why not just `{{foo[0]}}` which is the normal way to access the first element in foo array in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

In Spacebars, an array is still considered an object, with it's indices considered as properties. Therefore, they would have to be referenced using the dot notation:

```
{{foo.0}}
```

The semantic problem is: in an array, indices are integers, not strings. For this reason, when refering to an array's index, [a choice was made](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#identifiers-and-paths) to use the bracket notation on top of the dot one:

> A Spacebars path is a series of one or more identifiers separated by either `.` or `/`, such as `foo`, `foo.bar`, `this.name`, `../title`, or `foo.[0]` **(numeric indices must be enclosed in brackets)**.